# iOS7 UItextfield text disappear while coming from background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextfield

**Strange issue only in iOS7**

I do some entry in text field and then press home button of mobile and resume the app again, the data entered doesn't appears and only appears when I again start typing into the `UITextField`.

**Note:** Working fine in iOS6

[Sample Code](https://github.com/zoebsheikh/TextField_Issue)

Comment: I can't replicate this, can you show some code?

Comment: Simply added text field inside a view in iOS7, in my case its email field.
When I type some text and then press home button and coming again in foreground text not appear in textfield

Comment: Share some code. Because I tried the scenario you described above, but couldn't able to produce bug. It's working fine for me.

Comment: Hey John/Piyush

Please find the attached demo project, I think its because I set border style to none because when I change it to other it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because I set border style to none because when I change it to other it works fine

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. I replaced the textfield, reconnected the outlets and style it programmatically instead of style by storyboard. Good Luck!